# WatIn and NUnit: RequiresSTA assembly could not be found

Tags: c#, nunit, watin, .net-assembly

I am quite sure this issues has not yet been addressed before.

I am adding [assembly: RequiresSTA] to my AssemblyInfo.cs file in my C# project. 
But it does not like the RequiresSTA word.

VS states "The type or namespace name"RequriesSTA" could not be found (are you missing or using directive or an assembly reference?)".

I am referencing WatIn 2.1 and NUnit 2.4.1. 
I have added using nunit.framework & WatIn.core.

My C# project is output type 'Console Application' and target framework '.Net Framework 4'

Any suggestions?
Thank You

Comment: Surely it is because you forgot the *using* statement.  Put it in your source code file with the test code instead of assemblyinfo.cs

Comment: Hi
In my assembly code I have the following usings:
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using NUnit.Framework;
using WatiN.Core;

In my class code I have the following usings:
using System;
using System.IO;
using WatiN.Core;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers;
using WatiN.Core.Exceptions;
using WatiN.Core.Logging;
using NUnit.Framework;

Am I missing a specific using reference?

Comment: Hi

I have solved my problem.
I don't need the assembly: RequiresSTA.

Instead I just had to add [STAThread] above each of my functions (void's).

Thank you